# Nifi server start up issues

Tags: apache-nifi

I am Using Nifi 0.4.1 version. Am writing custom code to convert CSV to avro format. I have created class file(.java file) and able to generate nar file. Placed the newly created nar file in lib directory and restarted nifi server.

class file does not have any errors or warnings.

When I open a browser and typed localhost:8080/nifi, I am getting blank page in the browser. Also, command prompt is exiting from bin directory.

When checked status of nifi (status-nifi.bat), it is saying server might have crashed or hung up.

Any help appreciated..

Answer (score 2):

Look in the nifi-app.log and the nifi-bootstrap.log, they'll provide more information on why NiFi didn't start up.
The default location of these files will be in the nifi-root-directory/logs.

Comment: Dave is right.  Look at the bootstrap log to make sure there weren't any errors with the load.